# Saving the output files in a different location from the input ones

Tags: python, save

The "Resample_management" takes an input file, processes it and saves the output file in the same location with the input file.

```
Input=glob.glob("D:\Folder1\*tif")

for i in Input:
    arcpy.Resample_management(i, i+"_1000.tif", "1000 1000", "BILINEAR")
```

I am trying to save the output in a different directory from the one of the input file.
I have also tried the code below, but it did not work:

```
Input=glob.glob("D:\Folder1\*tif")

for i in Input:
    arcpy.Resample_management(i, "D:\Folder2\i"+"_1000.tif", "1000 1000", "BILINEAR")
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: It could simply be because you have unescaped backslashes in you file and path names -- you don't say exactly how "it did not work". To fix that either double them or add an `r` prefix to the string literals that contain them, i.e. `"D:\\Folder1\\*tif"` or `r"D:\Folder1\*tif"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If `Resample_management()` does what you say, namely create the output file in the same directory as the input file, then you have two options.

1. Move the file once it's created to where you want it.
2. Modify `Resample_management()` so that it does not create the output file in the same directory as the input file.

The second option may for various reasons not be feasible.